# Subfigures appear on different lines when one doesn't have caption

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I've got three subfigures in a row, and am setting their heights explicitly, as the first two are different widths, but need to appear the same height.  The third subfigure needs to caption (it's just a legend), but if I leave out its legend it appears on a a different line to the other two.

Making it yet more confusing, it appears on the line *above* the first two subfigures (even though it is the last subfigure).  Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \setlength{\subfigheight}{16em}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{caption1}
        \includegraphics[height=\subfigheight]{figures/VectorCorrelations0.pdf}
        \label{fig:vector_corr0}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{caption2}
        \includegraphics[height=\subfigheight]{figures/VectorCorrelations1.pdf}
        \label{fig:vector_corr1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\caption{I don't want this caption}
        \includegraphics[height=0.83\subfigheight]{figures/VectorCorrelationsColorbar.pdf}
        \label{fig:vector_corr1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{TODO do this caption}
    \label{fig:vector_correlations}
\end{figure}
```

If I uncomment out the line `\caption{I don't want this caption}`, the problem is fixed, but now I have an undesired caption..

Comment: You are explicitly controlling the figures' height, most probably this produces their combined width to exceed `\textwidth`, so an overfull box is produced and you get the undesired result. If you could post the actual images, that would really help us to provide the more sensible advise.

Comment: Please augment your code to make it into a standalone compilable document. Be sure to indicate which package you use to access an environment called `subfigure`. (There are several such packages; it should be your job to eliminate the guesswork.)

Comment: Once again, as it states in the subfig manual, "Do you really need this package?"  There is nothing subfigures do that can't be done better using a tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bottom alignment. The third narrow figure can be set with its top level to the other two images by using the additional optional arguments to `subfigure` (that's actually a `minipage`).

In the example I set the width for the images because I can't know how wide yours are.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newlength{\subfigheight}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tp!]
\setlength{\subfigheight}{16em}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{caption1}
  \label{fig:vector_corr0}

  \includegraphics[height=\subfigheight,width=.9\textwidth]{figures/VectorCorrelations0.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{caption2}
  \label{fig:vector_corr1}

  \includegraphics[height=\subfigheight,width=.9\textwidth]{figures/VectorCorrelations1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigheight][t]{0.05\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.83\subfigheight,width=\textwidth]{figures/VectorCorrelationsColorbar.pdf}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{TODO do this caption}
\label{fig:vector_correlations}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the legend to be vertically centered with respect to the two images, change

```
\begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigheight][t]{0.05\textwidth}
```

into

```
\begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigheight][c]{0.05\textwidth}
```